# i try to send a notification to a specific device flutter

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, flutter, firebase

iam working on a Chat app with flutter and i try to send a notification to a specific device  using firebase function and flutter first i get the token of the device and save the token at firebase now i try to get the token and call a function at index.js but i dnot know how to write a node js code

get token code

```
void getToken() async {
await fcm.getToken().then((value) {
  tokens = value;

  print('my token22 is $tokens');
  saveToken(tokens: tokens);
});
}

void saveToken({String? tokens}) async {
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userToken').doc(userphone).set({
  'token': tokens,
});
}
```

request permission code

```
void requestPermission() async {
NotificationSettings settings = await fcm.requestPermission(
  alert: true,
  announcement: false,
  badge: true,
  carPlay: false,
  criticalAlert: false,
  provisional: false,
  sound: true,
);

if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
  print('user get permissined');
} else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
    AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
  print('user is provisional');
} else {
  print('user declined');
}
}
```

itry to send FCM and its work successfully and also the token is add successfully no i want to call token and send notification to sepific token but i don't know how to write code with nodejs

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: i am no newer to javascript i do not know javascript i learning flutter and try to add node js code to my flutter app to apply firebase cloud function

Answer (score 0):

```
export const sendPush = https.onCall(
  async (data, context) => {
    const { userPhone } = data;
    const userDoc = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("userToken")
      .doc(userPhone)
      .get();
    const { deviceTokens } = userDoc.data();
    const title = `example title`;
    const body = "example body";

    try {
      if (deviceTokens) {
        await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceTokens, {
          notification: {
            title,
            body,
          },
          
        });
      }

      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new https.HttpsError("invalid-argument", "some message");
    }
  }
);
```

This is an example function to send a push notification to a device. You would need to install the flutter firebase cloud functions package the call the function in your flutter app and send the data.

In your cloud functions you have to install the firebase admin package to be able to query firestore.

Here is a link to the cloud functions documentation
[Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)

Comment: Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' this error appear when itry to add the function and I add const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();